# Python code to keep only a set of html tags in a input string

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have text like this:

```
<div>
  <script></script>
  <h1>name</h1>
  <p> Description </p>
  <i> italic </i>
</div>
```

I want to remove all html tags except h tags and p tags. For this I'm trying to make a more generic method like this:

```
def strip_tags(text, a_list_of_tags_to_not_remove)
```

Using the following Beautiful Soup code I can remove all the html tags, but it doesn't allow to keep a list of tags, while removing others.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  
cleantext = BeautifulSoup(raw_html).text
```

Can I do this using Beautiful Soup or are there any other python library to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can.

You can use [`.find_all([])`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-list) to find all the tags you don't care about, then call [`.unwrap()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#unwrap) to get rid of them while keeping the content.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [find_all](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all) function:

```
soup.find_all(['h1', 'p'])
```

to get a list of the tags you need, instead of having to find all the tags you don't want.